# javascript return true not working

Tags: javascript

i have used the following code for javascript validation, that return true or false depending on the condition

javascript block

```
function fnval()
{
 if(document.field.value == "")
 {
  alert("Invalid value");
   return false;
 }else{
   return true;
 }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<Input type=submit name="sub" onClick="return fnval()">
```

Thus the js block checks if the field value is entered or not. If not it throws an alert message and return false, and hence the form does not get submitted.
But in case the value is not empty it returns a true, and still the form does not get submitted.

I have seen some queries asked by people where return false results in submission of the form. But this is exactly opposite.. and am not able to find a solution as of now.
Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Is your `<input>` element inside a `<form>` element?

Comment: And you don't "throw" an alert message ;)

Comment: you should look at using jquery. Its a javascript library for working with elements on the page, just like you're attempting to do here. I'm not sure what `document.field` should return. Have a look into jquery, its so much easier and its cross browser compatible.

Comment: I suggest you check out VanadiumJS. It will make your life a hell of a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

Try [**getElementsByName**](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-71555259):

```
function fnval()
{
 if(document.getElementsByName('field')[0].value == "")
 {
  alert("Invalid value");
   return false;
 }else{
   return true;
 }
}
```

---

`getElementsByName` doesn't have IE support though. Perhaps:

```
function fnval()
{
 if(findInput('field')[0].value == "")
 {
  alert("Invalid value");
   return false;
 }else{
   return true;
 }
}
function findInput(name) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('input'),
        length = elements.length,
        i = 0,
        results = [];
    for(i; i<length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].name === name) {
            results.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: "getElementsByName doesn't have IE support though".  It works for me on IE9.

Comment: @recursive, http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t125 maybe they fixed it. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the form name and the form value. Something like:

```
if ( document.formName.fieldName.value == "" )
```

For instance, with this kind of HTML:

```
<form method="post" onsubmit="">
Password: <input name="password" type="text" /><br />
</form>
```

The js:

```
if (document.form.password.value == "") {
    //empty
}
```

Answer (score 2):

i suggest using `onsubmit` in the form, `<form ...  onsubmit="return fnval()">`, 
try adding that and placing `return false` at the base of your function.

Answer (score 0):

no matter what you do in js. but if you have filled action tag of form element element , the form will submit.

Answer (score -1):

Syntax error:

```
type="submit"
```

not

```
type=submit
```

Comment: browsers have no issue with this

Comment: Actually, no, for better or worse.

Comment: That's valid in HTML 4.01. (The quotation-marks requirement is added by XML.)